Calculating simple returns (one cell divided by cell above it in same column, result in another column) across large sets of data, google sheets
I'm trying to find a way to automate a simple return calculation (one cell divided by cell above it) across a large set of data which updates/adds cells regularly without having to pull-down the formula. I can't use arrayfunction as it gives me a circular error (all data is in same column). Perhaps there is a way to "split" the column into 2 virtual arrays and then just divide those? Or, another easier way?

Appreciate any and all help!

Another solution:
=ARRAYFORMULA(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(A2:A/A1:A-1,COUNTA(A2:A),1))



You may try this in Cell_B3:
=map(A3:index(A:A,match(,0/(A:A<>""))),lambda(Σ,Σ/offset(Σ,-1,)-1))



To easily take a copy of your sample data & test formulas (instead of us having to manually type from screenshots), the recommended method is creating a markdown table. Use this table generator to create the markdown_format & add it to your question. Another way is to share a sample sheet showcasing your input with realistic-demo data & expected output(manually entered). You may also use the anonymous blank sheet maker just in case

Ah ok...thanks. I'll do that in the future
